# Run Jenkins in Docker on RasPi4

Tags: jenkins, raspberry-pi

I cannot start Jenkins inside Docker using the official image.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts

COPY resources/init.groovy.d/executors.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/executors.groovy
COPY resources/jenkins-as-code-config.yaml /var/jenkins/home/jenkins-as-code-config.yaml
COPY resources/plugins.list /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.list

RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.list

ENV JAVA_OPTS -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false
ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG /var/jenkins/home/jenkins-as-code-config.yaml
```

I'm always getting this result (I'm using rundeck to control my raspi nodes hence the additional log output):

```
10:04:37    hal 1. Pull Jenkins Base Image  hal | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
10:04:37            lts: Pulling from jenkins/jenkins
10:04:37            Digest: sha256:1433deaac433ce20c534d8b87fcd0af3f25260f375f4ee6bdb41d70e1769d9ce
10:04:37            Status: Image is up to date for jenkins/jenkins:lts
10:04:37            docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:lts
10:04:51        2. Run Start Script     hal | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
10:04:51            [INFO] Change dir
10:04:51            [INFO] build docker image
10:04:51            Sending build context to Docker daemon  9.728kB
10:04:51            
10:04:51            Step 1/7 : FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
10:04:51             ---> 1920bf702d7d
10:04:51            Step 2/7 : COPY resources/init.groovy.d/executors.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/executors.groovy
10:04:51             ---> Using cache
10:04:51             ---> 3a49d6ea509e
10:04:51            Step 3/7 : COPY resources/jenkins-as-code-config.yaml /var/jenkins/home/jenkins-as-code-config.yaml
10:04:51             ---> Using cache
10:04:51             ---> b3c072b517f2
10:04:51            Step 4/7 : COPY resources/plugins.list /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.list
10:04:51             ---> Using cache
10:04:51             ---> 7de88ffa119c
10:04:51            Step 5/7 : RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.list
10:04:51             ---> [Warning] The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm/v7) and no specific platform was requested
10:04:51             ---> Running in 01df5b34c598
10:04:51            standard_init_linux.go:219: exec user process caused: exec format error
10:04:51            [DONE] Finished building docker image
10:04:51            [INFO] start rundeck container
10:04:51            [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------
10:04:51            [INFO] startup in progress (detached)
10:04:51            [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------The command '/bin/sh -c /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.list' returned a non-zero code: 1
10:04:51            Unable to find image 'jenkins-hal-image:latest' locally
10:04:51            docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for jenkins-hal-image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
10:04:51            See 'docker run --help'.
10:04:55        3. Show Containers  hal | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
10:04:55            CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND        CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                    NAMES
10:04:55            5a6a2d6fde0d   portainer/portainer:arm   "/portainer"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   0.0.0.0:9990->9000/tcp   raspi-portainer
```

So my question is: Is there an image for ARM architecture I can use?

Answer (score 0):

A bit if googling points to this dockerhub account: https://hub.docker.com/r/mlucken/jenkins-arm - don't know how  reliable this image is, though.